# Sample MS application for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am getting started with my first MVC project and want to start off on the right foot. I know the basics of how to create a quick and dirty MVC application. However, I'd like to get my hands on a resource that uses best practices for developing ASP.NET MVC applications (either a document or a sample quickstart app)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) is the seminal ASP.NET MVC example.  Once you've grokked that, move on to [Orchard CMS](http://orchard.codeplex.com/) for an amazing example of a totally loosely-coupled, IOC-based ASP.NET MVC app.

Answer (score 1):

NerdDinner is your best bet.

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

Answer (score 1):

[CodeCampServer](http://codecampserver.com/) is a reasonable sample application for some ideas and [S#arparchitecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/) if you want a quick skeleton to build your application around.

Answer (score 1):

I loved sutekishop. I used a lot of ideas in it in my project.

http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Web Client Guidance reference application, from Microsoft Patterns and Practices team http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/

Quote from "Overview":

> The Web Client Guidance
>   program from patterns & practices
>   assists developers and architects with
>   the design, development, and
>   deployment of rich, responsive,
>   modular, Web applications using the
>   .NET Framework and other Microsoft
>   technologies.