# Sample project to compare ASP.Net and ASP.Net MVC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to explain ASP.Net MVC 2 to my colleagues and the management. I have to develop a sample application in both ASP.Net and ASP.Net MVC 2 to show case the differences between the two.

What would be a good application that can bring out the differences between the two? I am planning to demonstrate performance and testability. Any other key points that I can demonstrate?

Any ideas is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're web developers that likes to keep up with all the latest stuff, show 'em your complete control over the generated source. Show them how they can create HTML5 compliant websites with no extra effort. No more (unless you want) viewstate or document wrapping form tags.

You could also show them the extensibility abilities with action filters and action results.

But, as you mentioned, the biggest win for everyone is **testability**.

Edit:
I can really recommend [TardisBank](https://github.com/mikehadlow/Suteki.TardisBank/tree/933a24bb97b53ba26e8a4044625c2e8a4cd2d8e9) as a great sample application. It uses MVC3 with Razor and RavenDB as the database. The code is well structured and clean.

Comment: Can the projects listed here be a good fit for comparision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638529/sample-ms-application-for-asp-net-mvc?

Comment: Yeah absolutely. NerdDinner is THE sample application of MVC. It also shows some nice aspects that's easy with MVC, like adding special views for mobile users.

Answer (score 1):

Show them the page size, that should be helpful

Comment: What a red herring. I'll repeat a regular comment: "I can write bad code in any language"

Comment: Not ViewStates, but ct001_bt239_asd0191_28981_FormView1_Panel12_FirstNameTextbox used as both the `name` and `id` of an element.

Comment: @marko ASP.NET 4 allows you to control those names too...another red herring.

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET 4 does. It hasn't been the case prior to it though.

Comment: @Marko ~ IIRC You could always override that if you wanted to, but it was a helluva lot of hassle.

Comment: most controls just don't work if you disable the ViewState, so it's kind of depended on that huge blob at the top of each page